# Duplicate an element on button-push with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery, and I'm trying to cause another identical dropdown menu to appear each time the user presses a button.  I thought this would work, where #append is the button id and #foo is the dropdown id:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#append").click(function(){
            $("#foo").append($("#foo"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, rather than duplicating the original dropdown, it causes it to disappear!  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#append").click(function(){
  $("#foo").parent().append($("#foo").clone().removeAttr("id"));
  });
});
```

[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) adds to the end of the element it was called on, so in this case you want to append to the parent, not **inside** the `<select>` element (like you would to add options).  Also, you want to [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) it unless you want to move the original instance.  Also make sure your IDs are unique, I'd remove the `id="foo"` and give it a class, or remove the ID on copies, etc...anything but duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to duplicate an element use [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

```
$("#foo").clone().attr("id", "foo2").insertAfter("#foo");
```

That being said, *don't* try and create your own menu. Use an existing plugin (there are many eg superfish). Menus have notorious cross-browser issues. There is no value in reinventing that particular wheel.